# checking kurtois and skewnes for normal variable

Tags: excel, statistics

i have generated   random variable according to  normal distribution in excel using technique of  analysis toolpak

[image]

what i need to know is that  why kurtois of  this  normal  variable is not equal to 3? here excel  formula for calculation of kurtois

```
=KURT(A2:A2001)  and its corresponding value is equal to `0.14521546`
```

does it mean that 3 is  only in case of infinity sample ? and for  specific amount of sample  range of amplitudes of  kurtois varies between -1 and  1? here is also  formula for calculation skewnes

```
=SKEW(A2:A2001)

-0.006510255
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Excel's KURT() function calculates excess kurtosis which is kurtosis-3.

Therefore it should be around 0 for a normally distributed random variable like in your case.